# How to get autogenerated folder path in java to parse files from a folder

Tags: java

In Unix created a folder path like `/data/test/files/2015/05/19`. From year, folder is autogenerated `/data/test/files/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m)/$(date +%d)`

So `.txt` file inside the above folder location should be parsed through Java code and moved to DB.

I tried to parse that location as `2015/05/19` will change in future, so tried to append current year/month/day in Java and then parse that particular file.

```
//To get current year
String thisYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date());
System.out.println("thisYear :"+thisYear);
//To get current month
String thisMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(new Date());
System.out.println("thisMonth : "+thisMonth);

//To get current date
String thisDay = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new Date());
System.out.println("thisDay : "+thisDay);

File f = new File("\\data\\test\\files\\+"thisYear"+\\+"thisMonth"+\\+"thisDay"+ \\refile.txt");
```

The above didn't work so how can I use `thisYear,thisMonth,thisDay` in path?

Comment: Folder separator (\\) is differ from unix (/)

Comment: Why need a star characters in file path?

Comment: @herry: It's not star, tried to make it bold +"thisYear"+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I think this works.

```
File f = new File("/data/test/files/" + thisYear+ "/" + thisMonth+ "/" +thisDay + "/refile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SimpleDateFormat class like:

```
String format = "yyyy/MM/dd".replace( "/" , File.separator );
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( format );

String pathPrefix = "/data/test/files/".replace( "/" , File.separator );
File f = new File( pathPrefix + sdf.format( new Date() ) + File.separator + "refile.txt" );
```

Remember that the path separator character is filesystem dependent, thus the `File.separator` usage. You might also replace the `new Date()` with something else, if you're not after "todays" directory.

If you need to scan through all date-formatted directories, that's another matter for another question, but do look at the `File.list()` methods for that.

Cheers,